# Trying to pass a constexpr lambda and use it to explicitly specify returning type

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr, stdarray

I would like to use a function and pass a `constexpr lambda`. However, it only compiles successfully if I let the type be deduced through `auto`. Explicitly giving the type through `-> std::array<event, l()>` seems to fail (the first instance). Why is this?

```
template <typename Lambda_T>
constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) -> std::array<event, l()> {
    return {};
} // error

template <typename Lambda_T>
constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) {
    return std::array<event, (l())>{};
} // OK

template <typename Lambda_T>
constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) -> decltype(l()) { return {}; }
// OK
```

Note that, the lambda returns a `size_t`.

gcc errors on this without a call (clang accepts it):

```
prog.cc:9:63: error: template argument 2 is invalid
    9 | constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) -> std::array<event, l()>
      |                                                               ^
prog.cc:9:63: error: template argument 2 is invalid
prog.cc:9:63: error: template argument 2 is invalid
prog.cc:9:63: error: template argument 2 is invalid
prog.cc:9:42: error: invalid template-id
    9 | constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) -> std::array<event, l()>
      |                                          ^~~
prog.cc:9:61: error: use of parameter outside function body before '(' token
    9 | constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) -> std::array<event, l()>
  |                                                             ^
prog.cc:9:23: error: deduced class type 'array' in function return type
    9 | constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) -> std::array<event, l()>
  |                       ^~~
In file included from prog.cc:4:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/9.0.1/array:94:12: note: 
'template<class _Tp, long unsigned int _Nm> struct std::array' declared here
   94 |     struct array
      |            ^~~~~
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:14:5: error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope
   14 |     foo([]() {return 3; });
      |     ^~~
```

Comment: What error do you get? ([mcve] please)

Comment: you miss `return {};` in first snippet.

Comment: Please, a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Compile fine with clang, but not with gcc [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9135b5c72e48948).

Comment: So the crux of the question is whether or or not it is legal to actually use a function parameter in a trailing return type.  `-> decltype(l())` is fine since the call to `l` doesn't actually happen, it is just evaluated.  `-> std::array<event, l()>` actually calls `l()` and since it isn't yet in block scope I don't know if that is legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters to constexpr functions are not themselves constexpr objects - so you cannot use them in constant expressions. Both of your examples returning `array`s are ill-formed because there is no valid call to them.

To understand why, consider this nonsense example:

```cpp
struct Z { int i; constexpr int operator()() const { return i; }; };

template <int V> struct X { };
template <typename F> constexpr auto foo(F f) -> X<f()> { return {}; }

constexpr auto a = foo(Z{2});
constexpr auto b = foo(Z{3});
```

`Z` has a `constexpr` call operator, and this is well-formed:

```cpp
constexpr auto c = Z{3}();
static_assert(c == 3);
```

But if the earlier usage were allowed, we'd have two calls to `foo<Z>` that would have to return *different types*. This could only fly if the actual value `f` were the template parameter.

---

Note that clang compiling the declaration is not, in of itself, a compiler error. This is a class of situations that are ill-formed, no diagnostic required.