# How does a compiler treat lambdas differently than regular functions?

Tags: c++, lambda, compilation, language-lawyer

I wonder how a compiler treats lambda functions as opposed to regular functions. Even excluding the capture-list, as I think it's called, it seems to behave slightly differently.

For example, as used in my last post, [Trying to pass a constexpr lambda and use it to explicitly specify returning type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353463/trying-to-pass-a-constexpr-lambda-and-use-it-to-explicitly-specify-returning-typ), I used a constexpr lambda and passed it as a regular function parameter. I quote a part of the answer.

> Parameters to constexpr functions are not themselves constexpr objects - so you cannot use them in constant expressions.

```
template <typename Lambda_T>
constexpr static auto foo(Lambda_T l) {
    return std::array<event, (l())>{};
} 
// Compiles with GCC (C++17), though ill-formed (according to the answer of my last post)
```

Though, what catches my eye is that this does compile passing a `constexpr lambda`, but does not compile passing a constexpr regular (global) function. What causes this difference? 
And are there other differences of behaviour of the compiler between regular functions and lambda-functions?

**Edit: Example of Lambda-implementation**

```
foo([](){ return 4; }); // C++17 Lambda's are implicitly constexpr
```

The lambda is basically a wrapper for the value in this case.

**Edit: Global function**

Whenever a global function is passed, the compiler will complain - as opposed to using a lambda - that this function, regardless of whether it is defined constexpr or not, cannot be used in a constant condition:

```
prog.cc:8:20: error: 'l' is not a constant expression
```

Comment: Can you show your lambda implementation?

Comment: It will compile if you pass any functor initialized by a constant expression. It will compile too if you replace `l()` by `fptr()` where `fptr` is a function pointer initialized by a constant expression. The only difference I see, is that when called with a function argument, the function-to-pointer conversion applied to the argument to initialize the parameter may not be assumed to be a constant expression. But I suspect in c++20 it should be assumed to be a constant initialization and in c++17 it is even more obscure.

Comment: @Oliv Oops, I just figured you already said the same thing while I was writing my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing some extraneous stuff from your snippet, we get

```
template<typename T>
constexpr void foo(T t)
{
    constexpr int i = t();
}

constexpr int f() { return 42; }
auto l = []{ return 42; }
```

Remarks:

1. You are attempting to use `t()` as a `constexpr` within `foo`. `foo` could in fact be a normal function and still behave the same.
2. A lambda *isn't* a function. It is an anonymous struct with an `operator()`.

   ```
   struct L { constexpr int operator()() const { return 42; } };
   ```

   `T` is deduced as a type equivalent to `L` in the call `foo(l)`.
3. `T` is deduced as `int(*)()` in the call `foo(f)`.
4. In both cases, `t` *isn't* a constexpr within `foo`.

---

From [[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2)

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions: [...]
>
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless [...]
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to a non-volatile object defined with constexpr, or that refers to a non-mutable subobject of such an object, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;

Calling through a `int(*)()` requires a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. `t` isn't an object defined with `constexpr`, neither did it begin its lifetime within the evaluation of `t()`. Therefore `t()` isn't a `constexpr` in `foo(f)`.

Calling `operator()` doesn't require a lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Since there is no member access, it is simply a `constexpr` function call. Therefore `t()` is a `constexpr` in `foo(l)`.

<sub>There is [one more step](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#5) from core constant expressions to constant expressions, but isn't important for the discussion here.</sub>