# Template array length as argument

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to learn more about templates in C++. I would like to be able to call a function where I pass it a type and the length as *an argument*. Is this possible?

```
template <class T>
void alloc_arr (int l) {
    std::allocator<T[l]> a;
}

alloc_arr<int[]>(64);
```

It doesn't work because the instantiated type must be fixed at compile time (`T[l]` is not fixed).

Is there some other way to do this which doesn't require the length to be specified in the type (`<T[64]>`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some other way to do this which doesn't require the length to be specified in the type ()?

In some way, you need to pass it as template parameter

You can pass it explicitly, as suggested by Lourens Dijkstra

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
void alloc_arr ()
 {
   std::allocator<T[Dim]> a;
   // ...  
 }
```

or, if you can use at least C++11, also you can deduce it from the type of an argument; by example,

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Dim>
void alloc_arr (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Dim> const &)
 {
   std::allocator<T[Dim]> a;
   // ...  
 }
```

or also

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void alloc_arr (U const &)
 {
   std::allocator<T[U::value]> a;
   // ...  
 }
```

calling `alloc_arr` with a `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 5u>{}`, by example.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for all the details.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the size as a `template parameter`:

```
template <class T, size_t size>
void alloc_arr() { ... }
```

This is the only way. A couple of days ago I found out that passing a `constexpr lambda` as a regular parameter is considered ill-formed: [Trying to pass a constexpr lambda and use it to explicitly specify returning type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353463/trying-to-pass-a-constexpr-lambda-and-use-it-to-explicitly-specify-returning-typ)

Also, note that type T should be `int`; not `int[]`.

So, calling alloc_arr:

```
alloc_arr<int, 64>();
```

Comment: I tried that and it works but it is not exactly what I was looking for. If it is not possible to have something like this `alloc_arr<int[]>(64)` how come there are functions like this in the standard library `std::make_unique<int[]>(64)`?

Comment: @zoecarver Because `std::make_unique<int[]>(64)` basically does `return std::unique_ptr(new int[64]);`  The value isn't actually part of the template type.